# How do I copy a dynamic range of data that follows a specific string from one sheet to another using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, dynamic, range

I am trying to search Sheet1 column a for the string "   Testing Test" (yes with the spaces beforehand) then copy all rows below the row containing this string until a blank row is found, then I want to paste this selected range into column A row 1 on Sheet2. Next I want to search for the string "            CASH" (again yes with the spaces beforehand) and i want to copy just the row that includes that to be pasted 2 rows underneath the last row of the first range pasted.

Here is what I have so far, which does not work... I do not even address the second component of finding the second string because i can't get the first... please assist, not sure why this is not working:

```
Sub Test()

Dim StringToFind As String

Dim i As Range

Dim cell As Range

StringToFind = "   Testing Test"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set cell = .Rows(1).Find(What:=StringToFind, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
                            
If Not cell Is Nothing Then

For Each i In .Range(cell.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp))

If IsNumeric(i.Value) Then

If i.Value > 0 Then

i.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

End If

End If

Next i


Else


End If

End With

                            

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it finding the cell with the string? You are restricting your search range to only the first row, is that intentional?

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would help here

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a little detail. However, the code below will point you in the right direction. If you need help to manage it, please ask.

```
Sub FindAndCopy()
    ' 221
    
    Dim WsS         As Worksheet            ' Source
    Dim WsT         As Worksheet            ' Target
    Dim Caps()      As String               ' captions to find
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' found caption
    Dim Tgt         As Range                ' Target
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' Value of Fnd
    Dim f           As Integer              ' loop counter: Caps
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WsS = .Worksheets("Sheet1")     ' change to suit
        Set WsT = .Worksheets("Sheet2")     ' change to suit
    End With
    Caps = Split("Testing Test,CASH", ",")  ' extend to suit
    For f = 0 To UBound(Caps)
        Set Fnd = WsS.Rows(1).Find(Caps(f), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit For
        
        Set Fnd = Fnd.Offset(1)
        If f = 0 Then Set Fnd = Fnd.Resize(Fnd.End(xlDown).Row - 1, 1)
        Arr = Fnd.Value                     ' copies Values, not Formulas
        
        With WsT
            Set Tgt = .Cells(1, 1)
            If f Then Set Tgt = Tgt.Offset(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            If VarType(Arr) >= vbArray Then
                Tgt.Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
            Else
                Tgt.Value = Arr
            End If
        End With
    Next f
End Sub
```

Observe that I discarded the leading spaces in your search criteria in favour of looking for a partial match in the `Find` function. In that way it doesn't matter how many spaces there are but it may cause confusion if there several matches. In that case you might reinstate the blanks by amending the array of `Caps`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. When I run this code, it does not produce any result. I want to copy all rows in their entirety immediately under the searched strings, in this case "Testing Test" and "Cash", until a blank row is found. Then the range being copied to sheet2 should end as there is irrelevant data in the document. Then the rows following both strings should be pasted into sheet 2. First pasting the rows following "Testing Test" then "cash" with a row separating them.

Comment: The code is tested. Rest assured it works. It may not work for you, however, because you try it in a different environment. Therefore, check the environment. Since the code doesn't crash, I presume that `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` exist. The most likely cause of failure is that the columns aren't found. The captions are looked for in row 1 of `WsS`. You may have to step through the code with F8 using the debugger and check the result for all relevant variables in the *Locals* window after each line was executed. Find out why the captions aren't found.

Comment: The rows that need to be copied will vary in where they are in Sheet1. I need the macro to look through every row of the sheet for "Testing Test" and "Cash" to copy the entire range of rows immediately following the rows containing the above strings until a blank row is found. Right now it seems like it is only looking in row 1, how can I make it look through every row?

Comment: Your latest comment describes your requirement different from your original question where the description was inadequate. I also feel that you conflate rows with columns and, obviously, you are not willing or able to debug code. Therefore you just repeat - or think you repeat - what you want without testing at what you got and properly informing the results. If you update your question I shall delete my answer and we start afresh.